# objective C adding an object to a view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

I am new to iPhone App Developpment , I am using XCode 4.2

I want to Implement a list similar to this one , but I don't know what is its name (it is a list of options that appears in the photo Album) :

[image: it is a list of options that appears in the photo Album]

Thanks

Comment: UIActionSheet
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `UIActionSheet` - [Apple Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
 options = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
               initWithTitle:nil
               delegate:self 
               cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"              
               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
               otherButtonTitles:@"Email Photo", @"Message", @"Assign to Contact", @"Use as Wallpaper", @"Tweet", @"Print", nil];

[options showInView:self.view];
[options release];
```